# determination of a volume of a solid being lifted

Tags: integration

i passed by  a question now and  wanted to check something, i want to calculate the volume of a given solid such that the solid is representedd by  K= ${ (x,y,z)\in R^3 / x^2 +y^2 \le \frac{1}{z^2}}$ and  ${1\lt z \lt 3 }$ my question is using cylindrical coordinates $r$ varies between {0 and $\frac{1}{z}$} or {1 and $\frac{1}{z}$}?

Answer (score 1):

Setting $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ you get the two following constrains :
$$
r^2 \leq \frac{1}{z^2} \overset{(*)}{\Leftrightarrow} r \leq \frac{1}{z}\\
1 < z < 3
$$
$(*)$ Since $r \geq 0$ with cylindrical coordinates.

Therefore $r$ ranges in $r \in [0,1/z]$ for a given fixed $z$ because we have an upper bound on $r$ but no (explict) lower bound.

Comment: okay, but for the surface area determination, r then has an lower bound of 1 ?

Comment: You first choose an "altitude" $z$ which is between $1$ and $3$. Then based on this choice, you make $r$ range between $0$ and $1/z$. (And also $\theta$ be in $[0,2\pi[$).
If you want the "integral domain" to compute the volume it will be something like :
$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_1^3 \int_0^{1/z} F(x,y,z) d\theta dz dr$.
(We also need to remember the Jacobian $r$ !)